# Handling multiple radio buttons in Quiz And also facing Cannot find control with path:

Tags: angular, typescript

Implementing a Quiz containing multiple MCQs. But I am having trouble in radio button selection.

My Questions are coming from the database and Options too.

**emp-training.component.html**

```
 <form [formGroup]="resultForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate> 
           <mat-accordion class="quiz-accordion" multi formArrayName="quizResultRequestList"
               *ngFor="let question of list.questionList; let i = index">
                   <div [formGroupName]="i">
                                                       
                        <mat-expansion-panel>
                           <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                             <mat-panel-title >
                               {{question.questionText}}
                             </mat-panel-title>
                           </mat-expansion-panel-header>

               <div formArrayName="questionList" multi *ngFor="let option of question.optionList; let k=index">
                                                        <div [formGroupName]="k">
                                                        <input type="radio" formControlName="selectedOptionId" [id]="i" value="{{question.id}}-{{option.id}}">
                                                        <mat-label>{{option.optionText}}</mat-label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </mat-expansion-panel>
                                            </div>
                                            </mat-accordion>
                                            {{resultForm.value | json}}
                                        </form>
```

Want to create output like below Json as unable to get exact output for multiple questions:-

```
{
   "employeeId":2501,
   "trainingId":1,
   "department":{
      "id":23
   },
   "quizResultRequestList":[
      {
         "quizId":2,
         "questionList":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "selectedOptionId":2
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "selectedOptionId":5
            },
            {
               "id":5,
               "selectedOptionId":13
            }
         ],
         "quizDuration":100
      }
   ]
}
```

**emp-training.component.ts**

```
createForm(){
    this.resultForm = this.fb.group({
      employeeId:[(JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('empDetails')).id)],
      trainingId:[this.id],
      quizResultRequestList:this.fb.array([this.initQuestion()])
    })
  }


  initQuestion():FormGroup{
    return this.fb.group({
      quizId:[this.quizIdTemp],
      questionList:this.fb.array([this.initOption()])
    })
  }

  initOption():FormGroup{
    return this.fb.group({
      id:[''],
      selectedOptionId:['']
    })
  }
```

Also facing error - Cannot find control with path:
[image]

Comment: What is MCQ anyway?

Comment: what is list.questionList value looks like? why are you using property values instead of  array of formControls?

Comment: @Chellappanவ 

```
questionList": [
        {
          "id": 23,
          "questionText": "What is your blood group?",
          "optionList": [
            {
              "id": 34,
              "optionText": "O+",
              "isAnswer": null,
              "timestamp": "2020-07-09T07:30:25.159+0000"
            },
            {
              "id": 44,
              "optionText": "A-",
              "isAnswer": null,
              "timestamp": "2020-07-14T06:20:14.944+0000"
            }
          ],
```

Comment: @Chellappanவ When i am inserting 'let question of list.questionList.controls' it shows nothing.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i am fetching data from ngFor so no need to mention the FormArray and FormControl just handle it on radio click event.